# The request for locale.properties of pdf.js returns 404

Tags: spring-mvc, pdf.js

I'm trying to set up PDF.JS in an SpringMVC application for displaying PDF-files. Therefore I want also to use the pdf-viewer that is shipped with PDF.JS.

But I'm having problems with the "locale.properties" file. The error returns an 404 for that file. I have also tried to enter the url directly in the browser-url. But same result. When I change the extension from "properties" to "txt" or "css" or "js" it will work - but that doesn't seem ethical.

any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I solve the problem now.
I added the mime-mapping in web.xml file
：This tag defines a mapping between a file extension and a MIME type.

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>png</extension>
    <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>      
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>js</extension>
    <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>properties</extension>
    <mime-type>application/octet-stream</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: Fixed it. In IIS, you go into mime types, then add one for .properties of application/octet-stream

Comment: yes,you are right.But I use tomcat server,and add the mime-mapping in web.xml file.Any way,thanks.